# How to Override CSS of Inner Elements of Lightning Web Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a dataTable component looke like below:

```
<template>
  <lightning-datatable
    class="pw-table"
    key-field="id"
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    hide-checkbox-column
  ></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Now I want write some custom css to make table header higher,

```
.pw-table {
  height: 300px;
}
```

but useless, so how I can do it?
I use loadStyle but failed, I dont know why?

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import accountCustom from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/accountCustom';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat Lightning base components as black boxes. The internal elements of an LWC are protected by the Shadow DOM and Lightning Locker. You cannot style them with your CSS, and you cannot interact with them via JavaScript.

You can style the top-level element (which is actually what you've done here), but you can't style elements within the component. See [CSS Style Sheets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css) in the Lightning Web Components Dev Guide.

> A parent component can style a child component, but it styles it as a single element.